# Extract XML data from SOAP Response in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, soap

I am using a Python script to receive an XML response from a SOAP web service, and I'd like to extract specific values from the XML response. I'm trying to use the 'untangle' library, but keep getting the following error:

*AttributeError: 'None' has no attribute 'Envelope'*

Below is a sample of my code. I'm trying to extract the *RequestType* value from the below

```
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <Response>\n  
            <RequestType>test</RequestType> 
        </Response>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Sample use of untangle

```
parsed_xml = untangle.parse(xml)
print(parsed_xml.Envelope.Response.RequestType.cdata)
```

I've also tried `parsed_xml.Envelope.Body.Response.RequestType.cdata`

Comment: I have not used untangle, but it is unclear how it handles XML namespaces (no information here: https://untangle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 3):

This will solve your problem, assuming you want to extract 'test'. By the way, i think your response should not have 'soap:Header/':

```
import xmltodict

stack_d = xmltodict.parse(response.content)
stack_d['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['Response']['RequestType']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find the `xml.etree` library to be more usable in this context.

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree
```

Then we need to define the namespaces for the SOAP Response

```
namespaces = {
    'soap': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
    'a': 'http://www.etis.fskab.se/v1.0/ETISws',
}

dom = Element.tree.fromstring(response.context)
```

Then simply find all the DOMs

```
names = dom.findall('./soap:Body',namespaces)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the code doesn't seem to work. It has an issue with 'Element' in your dom = Element.tree.fromstring command: NameError: name 'Element' is not defined

Comment: 1) Neither `requests` nor the `http://www.etis.fskab.se/v1.0/ETISws` namespace is used in the question. Referring to them is just confusing. 2) "find all the DOMs" is a strange phrase. `findall` does not find "DOMs", it finds elements. Please put more effort into the answer.